# How do I search within someone's tweets?

Tags: twitter, search

I remember Jeff Atwood ([@codinghorror](https://twitter.com/codinghorror)) had posted a tweet about a new website, but I can't seem to find the link.

Is there any way I can search within someone's tweets to find that link?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Remy Sharp wrote a website application that will search your, or someone else's tweets without the limitations Twitter imposes so you can search far further back in time. It's at http://snapbird.org/.

Comment: Is there a way to use it without twitter account?

Comment: Agree with kinokijuf it's pretty suspicious why they need your login details for this, even if "We will never post to your account. Promise."

Comment: I've written to plenty of API's. Some requests require a user to be signed in or have signed up for an access key. Since the user didn't sign up for a developer key it may be using their login session. Which means that you might be able to search farther back without this site if you are logged in and know the right request parameters. Just another perspective to the nefarious one.

Comment: The source is open. It's open source. https://github.com/remy/snapbird/blob/master/public/js/snapbird.js. From there, "we have to have the user's token to authenticate them with the proxy". Looks like you can fork the project.

Comment: I wrote https://snapbird.org and yeah, it sucks that it has to ask for full read/write from Twitter. It's because you can't search DMs without having write permission (which is just stupid). Obviously not ideal, but until Twitter changes their API, snapbird will need the full access (sorry!).

Answer (score 21):

There was an answer to the same question on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/6562/how-do-i-search-someones-tweets) that you can reference.

[Jonathan Sampson](https://superuser.com/users/519/jonathan-sampson)'s answer from that (now deleted) post:

> http://search.twitter.com
>
> ```
> from:username tax
> ```
>
> Or use Google:
>
> ```
> site:twitter.com/username tax
> ```

[image: Example of search by username]

Answer (score 6):

Twitter has an [advanced search form](https://twitter.com/#!/search-advanced) that you can use.

Answer (score 2):

Also note that Twitter does not retain an infinitely long history of messages, you may not be able to find a Twitter message from the past.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter’s advanced search isn’t available on the mobile app. If you’d like to search by date on the mobile app you can still do so the old-fashioned way using the “since:” and “until:” operators.

In addition to all your asnwers up there, there's another great search for old tweets. Click on **[Backtweets](http://backtweets.com/)**, it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you can remember what the site was about or a word or two from the tweet, twitter has an [advanced search](http://search.twitter.com/advanced) which allows you to specify a user's tweets to search

Answer (score 0):

I have got better results with https://queryfeed.net/ more relevant results although the website does have a downtime at times.