# Advanced Twitter search tricks?

Tags: search, twitter

Searching Twitter can be arduous. What are some tricks to [searching Twitter](http://search.twitter.com/)? Are there additional options outside of the ones listed on [Twitter's advanced search](https://twitter.com/#!/search-advanced) page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I search within someone's tweets?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9/how-do-i-search-within-someones-tweets)

Comment: Community Wiki?

Answer (score 5):

There are some interesting articles around about using advanced Twitter search techniques to narrow down results. Most simply use the functions on the a[dvanced search page](http://search.twitter.com/advanced) or [search operators](http://search.twitter.com/operators) to create interesting searches:

[7 "Secret" ways to use Twitter](http://www.twitip.com/7-%E2%80%98secret%E2%80%99-ways-to-use-twitter-search/)

[Take Advantage of Twitter Search Operators](http://webworkerdaily.com/2009/07/10/take-advantage-of-twitter-search-operators/)

Comment: Ahh...finally found out how to search by client "source:[CLIENT NAME]" - I had forgotten about this one.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've found that [Searchtastic](http://searchtastic.com) yields deeper historical search results than [Twitter's Search](http://search.twitter.com)

EDIT: Sadly Searchtastic has shut down.

Comment: Your searchtastic link is missing the .com. :) Looks pretty cool though!