# Search only through tweets of people I'm following

Tags: twitter, search, followers

Facebook has a feature that allows you to search through status messages that your friends have posted, but Twitter doesn't currently have that feature.

Is it possible via the official Twitter webapp or are there alternative web applications that would do this?

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9/how-do-i-search-within-someones-tweets

Comment: Related, but not quite the same. I'm looking for something that can search through my entire timeline at once.

Comment: I find it baffling to think that I can do this from within the official Twitter iPhone app, but not within Twitter's official web interface.

Answer (score 7):

[SnapBird](http://snapbird.org/) will do this once you've authenticated with it

[alt text http://cl.ly/1aem/Screen_shot_2010-07-07_at_23.01.15.png](http://cl.ly/1aem/Screen_shot_2010-07-07_at_23.01.15.png)

Answer (score 5):

Currently for the browser version you need to add `&pf=on` (**P**eople you **F**ollow) to the search string. E.g. searching 'something':

`https://twitter.com/search?q=something&src=typed_query&pf=on`

Comment: This is the one that works :)

Comment: On Twitter web for desktop, there is now also a radio button on the righthand sidebar. On the Twitter app you need to tap the button with the sliders to the right of the search field. But for direct linking `&pf=on` is excellent to know.

Comment: On current Elon's Twitter this only seems to search in your own tweets.

Answer (score 2):

You can now do this through the web interface of Twitter.com

When you search via the webapp, the results will show a filter of users between

> Top / All / People you follow

By default the results will come back filtered by Top.

Select *People you follow* to filter search results accordingly.

You will also notice the URL change/update to the following (on an example search of "watching"):

```
https://twitter.com/search?q=watching%20lang%3Aen&f=follows
```

The following is the part that says you're filtering results to only accounts you follow:

```
f=follows
```

Comment: No longer works.