# What's the best way to search for old tweets?

Tags: twitter, search

I find twitter search kind of buggy. Is there another way of doing that search?

I don't mean tweets from a user (I use Google for that). I mean tweets from history.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9/how-do-i-search-within-someones-tweets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is this one service I use [Topsy](http://topsy.com/). There are many more search engines which are based on tweets. Some of them are here - [9 search-related services for Twitter](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/9-search-related-twitter-service-to-help-you-find-tweets/7223/)

Answer (score 0):

[Twearchy](http://twearchy.appspot.com) will show you all your old tweets in a plain text single page view. You can then use the browser's find feature to search for keywords.