# Search for a specific word in all tweets for a given Twitter account

Tags: twitter, search

Given a particular Twitter profile, that contains tens of thousands of tweets, what is the best approach for:

a) downloading the text (with date) of all tweets

and/or

b) search for a specific word in all tweets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to search for a specific word (which, I believe, is what you meant by 'work') you can use [Twitter's Advanced Search](https://twitter.com/search-advanced). I've attached a screenshot which includes fields both for **Words** and for **People** where you can specify the word(s) and the account(s) you want to search through.
[image: Twitter Advanced Search]

You can also see the related question: [How do I search within someone's tweets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9/how-do-i-search-within-someones-tweets?rq=1)

Comment: excellent, thanks!!!my next question is, how can I search within a list?