# How do I find my retweets of a certain account?

Tags: twitter

On twitter, @Someone shared something interesting and I retweeted it. Some time passes, and now I want to read it again. Problem is, I tweeted and retweeted lots of other stuff, and also @someone also tweeted loads of different stuff. My retweets of said account should be countable though.

So I am interested in my retweets of @Someone's account. I tried twitter's [advanced search](https://twitter.com/search-advanced) but there doesn't seem to be that option. Did I miss the obvious or is there some other way I can search for my retweets of a certain account?

Comment: pls check this http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9/how-do-i-search-within-someones-tweets

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Currently (as of March 2019) this is what worked for me:

```
from:@someone filter:nativeretweets [KEYWORD(s)]
```

This shows all retweets of `@someone` (including the optional KEYWORD(s)). If you retweeted the same tweet you can use `@yourtwittername` instead of `@someone`.

Comment: How did you find this hidden feature? That's what I was looking for but I think the OP wanted to find all tweets from an account that he has retweeted. Your solution is to find all retweets of someone (which can be based on a keyword also), it is a bit different even if your solution can be an alternative in some cases. Is it possible to find all tweets from an account that we have retweeted?

Comment: I am sorry, I can not remember where I found that info. I tried to look it up, but the closest I found is: https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/advanced-tweetdeck-features


This was helpful too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316172/difference-between-filterretweet-and-filternativeretweets-in-twitter-search

Comment: Can't find retweets older than a year through this.

Comment: `filter:nativeretweets` is nifty but this does not answer the question. This allows me to find things that @someone retweeted. I want to find tweets authored by @someone that *I* retweeted.

Comment: @Alec it looks like Twitter does not provide an official way to do it but you can use this script: https://gist.github.com/baptx/1525f338d93fa01db4e0
In my case `filter:nativeretweets` was limited to the last 7 days. The script I made does not have this limit but the Twitter API is limited to your last 3200 tweets.

Comment: @Alec `from:@yourtwittername filter:nativeretweets @someone [KEYWORD(s)]` should give you the tweets authored (or retweeted) by @someone that you (@yourtwittername) retweeted.
I just noticed that this only(?) works if the the search filter is set to "People you follow". It does not seem to work with the filter "From anyone".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid tweets that contain "Please RT" in the results, you may want to search for

```
from:someone +RT @yourtwitteraccount
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work any more.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that doesn't require to login with any account is [Topsy](http://topsy.com/tweets), a service for searching old tweets (and more). You could retrieve all tweets from @ someone and filter RT for the retweets. It's similar to snapbird as suggested in @plain-jane's comment.

Then search for: `from:@someone`

You can add others terms in the search also (see option advanced search). And don't forget to select 'All time' in the left sidebar for search all twitter history.

Retweets can't be obtained directly. You'll have to click next and search for 'RT' or to program a script that automacally retrieve all the tweets starting by 'RT'.

Comment: (Update 2019) Topsy is dead

Answer (score 0):

Try this **from:someone +RT** in the search bar. The first part gets the tweets from the user and the second part +RT gives you the retweeted tweets.

Comment: This doesn't work as of 2017 July.