# How do you search for a post by a user on Twitter?

Tags: twitter

There is a user I follow on Twitter and I'm trying to find a message they posted a while ago. I tried using Twitter search to search "@username searchterm" and there were no search results. How do I search for "searchterm" of "@user"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [advanced search](https://twitter.com/search-advanced) to look for tweets from a specific user. It's also possible to do your search with the operator `from:` e.g. `searchterm from:username`.

There used to be a history limit on searches on twitter.com, but this has been removed.

Comment: Best is to put `from:username` in parentheses: `searchterm (from:username)`.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter search can *apparently* only search back 10 days.

Try using **[Snap Bird](http://snapbird.org/)**.

You can:

> (search) .. someone else's tweets without the limitations Twitter imposes so you can search far further back in time

[Source](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/120/104588)