# Search for tweets with special characters

Tags: twitter

I want to find tweets with links with the `ob://` URI scheme:

- [Example 1](https://twitter.com/markjeffrey/status/718188127114776576)
- [Example 2](https://twitter.com/etherdesignlab/status/720951186749304832)

I have tried doing advanced search for the string `ob://` but the `://` get stripped off.

How can I filter tweets with the string `ob://`?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you cannot through Twitter. (Please also have a look at the edit further down the answer)
Your other option would be a Google search of `ob://" site:twitter.com/openbazaar`.

#### Why you cannot through Twitter

Certain special characters are reserved by Twitter as [Search/Query Operators](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search).

**Search/Query Operators**
[image: operators]

Both `:` and `/` are part of them.
Notice the "*list:NASA/astronauts-in-space-now*" example.

To demonstrate, try a search with just  `://`.
[image: no results 01]

Twitter will not even acknowledge the presence of `:` or `/`.

You get the same results as for a search for `#@`.
[image]

In your case (to my understanding) the way to find other users of OpenBazaar would also be through the software ([View OpenBazaar listings and stores](https://blog.openbazaar.org/openbazaar-user-tutorial/)).

---

### EDIT

After further looking into the issue I found there is a third party application that has no problem and will produce results for you.
It is called [Snap Bird](http://snapbird.org/).
There is even an [old answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/120/117311) within the webapps site.

In order to use the application you must give it access to your Twitter account.
When you finish with your search, if you want, you can revoke access to your account under the Settings tab (Settings--> Apps)

[image: Twitter Settings]

### EDIT #2

Following the [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/92196/search-for-tweets-with-special-characters/92817#comment81561_92817) by [Randomblue](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/13896/randomblue).

As per the app's home page instructions.

One can look for the following:
[image: instructions-01]

at:
[image: instructions-02]

One can keep on clicking the "*Search more tweets*" till all of them are searched.
[image: search more]

Comment: @Randomblue Please have a look at my second edit.

Comment: It seems the search is limited to someone's timeline. (In the example, @Schilling's timeline.) Have you been able to make a search over the whole of Twitter?